# "For IE (to) render them"

Tags: verbs, infinitives, for-to-complementizers

Which sentence is correct?

> I just put `&nbsp;` in the empty  elements for IE **to render** them.
>
> I just put `&nbsp;` in the empty  elements for IE **render** them.

The render will be processed by IE and not me, so putting `&nbsp;` will make IE render  elements.

Comment: The first one is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only the sentence with *to* is correct.